# SQL FULL JOIN over 6 tables

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have several tables. Can Someone tell me which join I have to use?

```
Table Factory : FactoryId, FactoryName

Table Person: PersonId, PersonName

Table Activity : AcitivityId, AcitivityType

Table FactoryPersonActivity: FactoryID, PersonId, ActivityId

Table AcitivityLead: AcitivityId, LeadId

Table Lead: LeadId, LeadType, LeadMethod
```

Now the question: I want all Leads(details) from a certain Factory. Can someone tell me what the join statement has to be?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  l.LeadType,
  l.LeadMethod
  f.Name
  p.PersonNASme,
  ...
FROM Factory f 
INNER JOIN FactoryPersonActivity fpa ON f.FactoryId    = fpa.FactoryID
INNER JOIN Person                  p ON fpa.PersonID   = p.PersonId
INNER JOIN Activity                a ON fpa.ActivityID = a.ActivityId
INNER JOIN AcitivityLead          al ON a.AcitivityId  = al.AcitivityId
INNER JOIN Lead                    l ON a.LeadId       = al.LeadId
WHERE f.FactoryID = $id;
```

Please read more about `JOIN`:

- [**JOIN(SQL)**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)
- [**Coding Horror: A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)
- [**Code Project: Visual Representation of SQL Joins**.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: @PieterTwentyeight - Sorry I missed it. Fixed now. See my edit.